# Typescript definition file for to$q

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, breeze, q

I am hoping that I can get some help. I have been trying use to$q in an angular application that I am trying to describe using typescript. But I am struggling. I have tried to create a type definition file as follows:

```
/// <reference path="../q/Q.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../angularjs/angular.d.ts" />

declare module breeze.core {
    export function extendQ(rootScope: ng.IScope, q: Q.Promise<any>): any;
    export function to$q(qPromise: Q.Promise<any>, success: any, fail: any): any;
}
```

But the javascript code is acting more like a c# extension method and I dont know how to achieve a similar affect with typescript. Note that I have only basic experience in javascript and that breeze is compleletely new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's good to know, @basarat.

But more important ... we have deprecated `to$q` in favor of using `$q` for promises throughout your Breeze app.  That's right. Breeze no longer depends on **Q.js** (although that remains the default).

Please use [**Breeze.Angular.Q**](http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/breezeangularqjs) instead. It is available as a [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Breeze.Angular.Q) or directly [from GitHub](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Breeze.Client/Scripts/Labs/breeze.angular.q.js). See the Breeze Labs [documentation for it](http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/breezeangularqjs).

You simply configure Breeze to use the `$q` instance for your app module and then write your breeze code against `$q` promises. For example

```
var promise = entityManager
   .executeQuery(query)
   .then(successCallback)
   .catch(failCallback) 
   .finally(finalCallback);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I have followed your instructions and the net result is success!! Oh, and it was a breeze. Thanks again. Keep up the great work.

Answer (score 3):

$q is defined in angularjs type definitions [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/af81415504b4edce8dac8446d96857f8018c6e9f/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L999)

You should not need to reference q.d.ts

Comment: Thanks I have taken this into account also. Cheers

Comment: This is now line `999` just FYI

Comment: Cool. I've turned it into a stable (git sha) link now ;)